# How to link to a specific photo or post in the Facebook app

Tags: ios, facebook, applinks

I'm trying to link to a specific post on a public Facebook page from my iOS app. I thought for sure that App Links would be the solution to this, as it's something that Facebook itself developed. Of course, Facebook doesn't actually implement any App Links metadata on the website. Hard to take a technology seriously when they won't even do it themselves.

So does anyone know how to do this? I'd rather not link to Safari, opening the Facebook app is definitely a better way to go. The fb:// protocol seems to be deprecated and doesn't work anymore. Facebook launches, but just goes to the news feed.

Comment: attach with photo link

Answer (score 0):

If you right click on the date/time of your post, then you will get a permalink to the post. You can try linking to that directly.